# Use bash syntax after a here document

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ftp

I need to create a script that connect to an ftp server, and check the size of some backups and compare them to the size of the local back-up.
My script looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/archives/
j=0
array=( $(find -type f -name "*.gz") )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    gunzip -c $i | tar t > /dev/null
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]
    then
    echo "The file $i might be corrupted. You might check it"
    exit 1
    fi
    size[$j]=$(stat -c%s "$i")
    echo "${size[$j]}"
    ((j+=1))
done
echo "BackUp is correct. Checking md5sum..."
ftp -inv $ftp_host << EOF
quote USER $ftp_login
quote PASS $ftp_password
binary
cd $ftp_path
j=0
array=( $(find -type f -name "*.gz") )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    size[$j]=$(stat -c%s "$i")
    echo "${size[$j]}"
    ((j+=1))
done
EOF
```

But it's just entering the content of the [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) like commands in my ftp...

So how can I do loop and condition in this situation?

Comment: You cannot execute arbitrary shell code on the FTP server. The best you can do is download the list of files to your local machine, and do the comparisons there.

Comment: @chepner I need to run this script every weeks in VERY BIG FILES so download the files isn't a very good option.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov All the data from the file must go from one server to the other anyway in order to compare them.

Comment: Not the files, just their names and sizes.

Comment: @chepner ah yes good idea, I don't thought about it. For exemple I store their name and their size in a file, and i send this file back to my server ? But how can I redirect ouput in a file in an ftp ?

Comment: @User112638726 Yeah, but not 2 time(server to ftp , ftp to server).

Comment: `ftp ... <<EOF > ftp-output.txt`, with the rest of the here-document following as usual. (I can't help you with actually retrieving the file names and their sizes from `ftp`; I haven't used `ftp` in decades.)

Comment: Note that the FTP `dir` command (or `ls` or `ls -l`) will usually give you some approximation to the file names and sizes (and maybe some other data) in the directory.  You may be able to simply fetch that information and analyze it, or you may have to fetch the list of names using one FTP command and then generate a sequence of operations (copy, or whatever) and process them properly in a second FTP command.  The details of the format of the output depend on the specific FTP server.  If the file names are not sober (names without spaces, newlines, etc), then go home now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finished my script with your help !
I post it may be some people can be interested.

```
#!/bin/bash

ftp_host=localhost
ftp_login=*********
ftp_password=*******
ftp_path="**********$"
nbr_file=2

cd /var/archives/
j=0
array=( $(find -type f -name "*.gz") )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    gunzip -c $i | tar t > /dev/null
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]
    then
    echo "The file $i might be corrupted. You might check it"
    exit 1
    fi
size[$j]=$(stat -c%s "$i")
((j+=1))
done

echo "${size[@]}" > local_output

echo "open $ftp_host
user $ftp_login $ftp_password
binary
cd $ftp_path" > /tmp/ftp.$$

i=0
while [ $i -ne $j ]
do
    echo "size ${array[$i]}" >> /tmp/ftp.$$
    ((i+=1))
done
echo "quit" >> /tmp/ftp.$$
ftp -ivn < /tmp/ftp.$$ > ftp_output
rm /tmp/ftp.$$
cd /root/backup/
./compare-size $nbr_file
if [ "$?" -eq "1" ]
then
exit 1
else
echo "The backup seems to be good !"
exit 0
fi
```